# Creating a DOM element on the fly, but fading it in

Tags: jquery, dom, fade

I'm having a problem creating a DOM element, appending it to another element and having it fade into place.

This doesn't seem to work:

```
$('<div/>').html('hello').appendTo('#parentDiv').fadeIn();
```

Can anybody put me on the right track

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
$("<div>hello</div>").hide().appendTo("#parentDiv").fadeIn();
```

or alternatively set display none instead of hide().

Comment: dammit! John has made jQuery too easy. I should have realized that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$('<div/>').html('hello').appendTo('#parentDiv').hide().fadeIn();
```